# Web Service Client - Construction Failing Due To Timeout (Proxy Issue)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, proxy

I have a webservice in Java 1.6 that extends `javax.xml.ws.Service`. The WSDL URL is located at an HTTPS endpoint and I am behind a corporate proxy (NTLM I believe). I have the proxy host, port, username, and password. I have verified that I can access the WSDL using `curl` if I specify the proxy in my `.curlrc` file. When the constructor is called it will eventually timeout with the error:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://www.blah.com/myservice.asmx?wsdl. It failed with:
>           Connection timed out.

The call that fails is:

```
public MyService_Service() {
    // this call to super is the one that times out
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), MYSERVICE_QNAME);
}
```

I have tried the following but none of the solutions work.

- [Client Webservice in java - proxy authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515604/client-webservice-in-java-proxy-authentication)
- [Java Web Service client basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071366/java-web-service-client-basic-authentication)

What can I do to call the web service from behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding the following code before the server instantiation:

```
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "myproxy.com");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");
```

Strangely this worked when I tested it by setting the VM options `-DproxyHost` and `-DproxyPort` so then searched for how to set it programmatically.